# Usage case for conda vs. linux environment modules

Tags: conda, environment-modules

I am familiarizing myself with `conda` and `linux environment modules` (`lems` henceforth), largely for the purpose of enabling reproducible research. I know that `conda` is more geared towards setting up user-level environments compatible across many platforms (HPC, laptops, etc), where as `lems` are generally geared towards HPC and usually deployed system-wide.

However, what is unclear is whether I can use `conda` to largely replace `lems`, given the caveat that when using `conda` many binaries will be duplicated if each user manages their own `conda` stack.

So, from a user's perspective, are there any distinct limitations to `conda` or `lems` that would require learning how to use both?

Comment: One HPC I use is moving away from modules and using [singularity containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(software)) instead. Containers are much more reproducible, though there is a learning curve.

Comment: Yup. The idea we have here is also that, specifically to define environment using conda and put conda within docker/singularity. Issue I see is whether we still need linux modules, as this can still be used within docker/singularity to load specific versions of gcc, for example. Or just use sigularity/docker to install the specific version of whatever conda can't handle? Clearly, there are many ways to approach this...